# Does Germany contribute 1/3 of the EU budget?

Tags: europe, germany

This morning I heard an interview with a german politician in the DLF (Deutschlandfunk) and he said something like

> Germany is already contributing 1/3 of the whole EU budget.

when asked, why he does not support the idea of the Euro bonds.

The podcast of this can be [found here](http://www.deutschlandfunk.de/interview.693.de.html)

Is this true? Does Germany really contribute 1/3 of the EU budget?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but the answer could be found by entering "EU budget" in a search machine and reading the top hit...

Comment: @DevSolar I am totally fine with this. Could've done this before ;)

Comment: -1 That link goes 'nowhere': a list of all past podcasts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What exactly do you consider a state's "contribution"? Absolute payment? *Net* payment, substracting the payments the state *receives* in regional support, as part of the Common Agricultural Policy etc.?

But judging by the [readily available numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_of_the_European_Union#EU-28_contributions_.282014.29), the answer would be:

**Germany does NOT contribute 1/3 of the whole EU budget.**

But it *is* the primary contributor, at **a bit over 22%** for the 2014 budget, after contributing slightly *under* 20% in 2007-2013.

Comment: I do not even know what he meant, I just thought this was impossible. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Looking at the net contribution of the 10 countries, which  actually pay more than they get back in subsidies and investment support (numbers from 2014), Germany actually covers about 36% (17,658.5 of 49,612.2 million €).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: But that is not what "contributing to the budget" means, is it? That would be "net payment" or something along those lines; the *budget* is higher, and those countries *getting* more than they pay are *still* contributing to it.